# ¿Cómo sacar fechas en respuesta SQL aunque no haya registros de esas fechas?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Actualmente tengo una consulta en ORACLE que me devuelve los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve que entre el día 11 y 13 no se han hecho pedidos, y necesitaría que si algún día no se han realizado pedidos, aparezca el día vacío de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que tengo actualmente es la siguiente:

```
select
    TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') AS FECHA,
    PEDIDO,
    COUNT(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS CANTIDAD
FROM PEDIDOS_TIENDA
GROUP BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd'), PEDIDO
ORDER BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Preguntando en el foro en inglés, me dieron la siguiente solución, la comparto por si a alguien le viene bien:

```
SELECT c.fecha,
       t.pedido,
       COALESCE(t.cantidad, 0) AS cantidad
FROM   (
         SELECT min_fecha + LEVEL - 1 AS fecha
         FROM   (
           SELECT MIN(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS min_fecha,
                  MAX(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS max_fecha
           FROM   PEDIDOS_TIENDA
         )
         CONNECT BY LEVEL - 1 <= max_fecha - min_fecha
       ) c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') AS FECHA,
                PEDIDO,
                COUNT(TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd')) AS CANTIDAD
         FROM   PEDIDOS_TIENDA
         GROUP BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd'), PEDIDO
         ORDER BY TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') ASC
       ) t
       ON c.fecha = t.fecha
ORDER BY fecha, pedido
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741255/how-can-i-get-all-dates-in-a-query-if-there-is-not-data-in-that-dates/68742551#68742551

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas tener una tabla con todas las fechas para poder hacer un outer join con esa tabla. Algo así:

```
select
    C.FECHA,
    PT.PEDIDO,
    COUNT(PT.PEDIDO) AS CANTIDAD
FROM PEDIDOS_TIENDA PT
RIGHT JOIN CALENDARIO C ON TRUNC(FECHA_PEDIDO, 'dd') = C.FECHA
GROUP BY C.FECHA, PT.PEDIDO
ORDER BY C.FECHA ASC
```

Comment: La cosa es que debería hacer esto sin crear tablas adicionales, pero gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Las tablas de calendario son una muy buena herramienta en todas las bases de datos. A fin de cuentas, estás simulando crear una en tu solución. Platica la posibilidad de crearla con tu equipo.